# Unable to bring bootstrap modal-panel in java server faces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

Here i am trying to implement bootstrap model-panel in my xhtml page using .
 The Problem i am facing is that my button is not able to call modal panel.

I had even tried javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('richPanel'); but this is also not working.

I had also tried to include cdn of bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and jquery cdn but that approach did'nt work as well.

At the time of using $('#myBootModal').modal('show'); i am getting an error in chrome debugger. Uncaught typeerror: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined.

My code is as follows:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
            xmlns:birt="http://jsf4birt.components"
            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:rtb="http://hubanalyzer.globalss.com/rtb">



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"></link>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

<script src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

</script>-->

```
<div class="MMGraphs">
    <div class="mProductivityHeading">
        <h:outputText value=" Manual Match Rule Productivity" style="color:black;background-color:#E0E0E0"/>
        <a4j:commandLink  id="myBtn" onclick="$('#myBootModal').modal("show");">
            <img src="../resources/images/popup.png" width="14px" height="14px" align="right" style="margin-top:2px;"/>
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </div>
    <div class="MMProductivity" id="ManualMatchProductivity"></div>
    <div class="mEffectivenessHeading">Manual Match Rule Effectiveness</div>
    <div class="MMREffectiveness" id="ManualMatchEffectiveness"></div>
    <div class="mDistributionHeading">Manual Match Record Distribution</div>
    <div class="MMRDistribution" id="ManualMatchDistribution"></div>
    <div class="mQualityHeading">Manual Match Rule Quality</div>
    <div class="MMRQuality" id="ManualMatchQuality"></div>
</div>

<rich:modalPanel id="myRichPanel" width="350" height="100">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="Modal Panel"></h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/modal/close.png" styleClass="hidelink" id="hidelink"/>
            <rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="hidelink" operation="hide" event="onclick"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="This panel is called using Component Control Component"></h:outputText>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Closure link (X) works also through Component Control"></h:outputText>
</rich:modalPanel>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myBootModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well for one if you don't need AJAX there's no point in using a4j:commandButton. Secondly can you provide a better example? You didn't say what is the part that you need to fix. The code you're showing doesn't contain the things you're describing and contains lot of things you don't need to show.

Comment: Thanks for the vital point.
 I need to call bootstrap modal panel that is in <a4j:commandLink> where i am supposed to call $('#myBootModal').modal("show"); inside onclick event.
This is where the problem is arising.
After placing that code inside onclick event..
I am getting element.styles undefined error in firebug.